# Select range around a value to view in R

Tags: r

I am looking to select 3 values above every Event=x to view in a table. My data is as follows:

```
    Event   
1     a
2     b
3     c
4     a
5     x
6     c
7     a
8     b
9     c
10    x
```

This is what I would like for a return:

```
    Value
1     b
2     c
3     a
4     a
5     b
6     c
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)

Event <- as_data_frame(c("a","b","c","a","x","c","a","b","c","x"))
names(Event) <- "Event"

Event %<>%
  filter(lead(Event,3)=="x" | lead(Event,2)=="x" | lead(Event,1)=="x")
```

Hope this helps. The lead and lag function are useful, although when you apply it you should be very careful about how the data is grouped and arranged/sorted. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a base R solution

```
Event = c("a","b","c","a","x","c","a","b","c","x")
xs = which(Event == "x")
lag = sort(c(xs-3,xs-2,xs-1))
Event[lag[lag > 0]
# [1] "b" "c" "a" "a" "b" "c"
```

`which` returns the index of the TRUE values in a logical vector.  In this case, which positions are "x".  We can then decrement the index by 1, 2 and 3 to get the lagged positions.

Now, `which` can be dangerous because if there's nothing meeting the condition then it returns a length 0 vector which can wreak havoc.  In this case though, it's OK because you'll get a length 0 vector as output.

```
xs_bad = which(Event == "y")
lag_bad = sort(c(xs_bad - 3,xs_bad - 2,xs_bad - 1))
Event[lag_bad]
# character(0)
```

`which` can bite you in another way, too.

```
Event_bad = c("a","x","a","b","c","x")
```

Now there's an "x" that's not even 3 positions away from the beginning.

```
xs_bad = which(Event_bad == "x")
lag_bad = sort(c(xs_bad - 3,xs_bad - 2,xs_bad - 1))
lag_bad
# [1] -1  0  1  3  4  5
```

Negative indexes can't be mixed with non-0 indexes so our last step will fail.  Defensively then we can change the code to remove this chance.

```
Event_bad[lag_bad > 0]
# [1] "a" "a" "b" "c"
```